# Accessing a file in java

Tags: java, xml, file

I'm trying to access this file:

```
File file = new File("C:\AISHU\formtest2.xml");
```

But I get this error:

*Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )*

It works fine if I use:

```
File file = new File("C:\\formtest2.xml");
```

But I don't want to store the file directly in my drive. How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `File` in 2015. Use java.nio.file. See `Paths`, `Files`.

Comment: @fge, you're relentless :-) (You know all your comments will be obsolete in a year ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape every backslash:

```
new File("C:\\AISHU\\formtest2.xml");
```

or you can use  slash instead:

```
new File("C:/AISHU/formtest2.xml");
```

it works also under windows.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `double \`. `\` is a special character in `java` and make take the following character as special character.

for example within `String` `\n` means new line and `\\` means `\`

try this :

```
File file = new File("C:\\AISHU\\formtest2.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

It tries to escape `A` from `AISHU` using the `\` and complains, since it is not a valid escape. Since you do not want it to be treated as an escape character, you have to escape the `\` itself using `\\`.

```
File file = new File("C:\\AISHU\\formtest2.xml");
```